# Proposing synonym on low-traffic tags [folding] <= [code-folding]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

[code-folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-folding) and [folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folding) <strike>are obviously</strike> (seem to be) synonyms

The problem is these seem like low-traffic tags and the specific user who wishes to propose synonym does not have enough reputation on the tag(s).

What is an appropriate way to handle this scenario?

Comment: So, these 2 tags should be folded into 1

Comment: Can anyone downvoting please provide an explanation? This seems like a perfectly reasonable request to me (the excerpts are pretty much identical). If there are objections I'm not seeing, please enlighten me.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Some of the [tag:folding] questions don't have to do with IDE: [Expression folding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46181098/), [animation folding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42331517), and [folding dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46773694) (yeah, the last 2 are bad, but still..). The [tag:folding] tag needs to cleaned up first before it's synonymized.

Comment: After re-reading the title, it seems the proposal is from [tag:code-folding] to [tag:folding]? Honestly, I'd prefer [tag:code-folding] as the master tag since it's clearer.

Comment: Expression folding, like left-fold and right-fold, is a common cross-language feature that one can have expertise in.  So having "folding" be the name for code-folding thing has an issue there.

Comment: @AndrewT. Good reply. I agree the synonym probably should be reversed, that way it's more explicit and avoids confusion, and I agree with the cleanup (bad questions that would be wrongly tagged too _especially_ warrant a cleanup in my opinion). I'm not sure how this question should proceed though. Maybe OP can post a different request for a cleanup, and then the synonym can be added later.